# how to check javascript preloader worth or not

Tags: javascript

hi am using this snippet for preload image using javascript

```
window.onload=function(){

heavyImage.src = "images/qq-lookupbody-holder.png"; (ON PAGE LOAD)

}
```

But am not find any different after i added this js snippet,

Is there any way to check , the preloader  script is really worht or not....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing it in a page "load" handler, it won't help because "load" isn't called until the images are ready. Call it before that, however, and it could make a difference, maybe, though one way or the other the browser has to fetch the image. Things like that can help when you preload images for *other* pages on your site. That gets them into the browser cache, so that when the user reaches a page that actually uses the image, it's cached.

Also, you didn't post it, but I assume that the line of code you supplied actually follows a line where "heavyImage" is set to an actual "Image" instance:

```
heavyImage = new Image();
```

*edit* — well after your update I can tell you that under no circumstances will that code help to load your image.  Again, you can try this:

```
var heavyImage = new Image();
heavyImage.src = "images/qq-lookupbody-holder.png";
```

Don't put that in an "onload" handler however. Just put it in a `<script>` block in the `<head>` of the document. Still, it may or may not really help. If you can arrange to preload the image on a page *before* your site visitor reaches the page with the image, then that could make a big difference.

Comment: How should i test preload img

Comment: Put it in the `<head>` but make sure you **don't** put it in a "window.onload" handler.  To test it, you could use some sort of plugin like Firebug or TamperData to see whether the image is being fetched from cache or from your server. (Note that you should make sure your server is setting up the correct headers to make the image cacheable.)

Comment: i downloaded the tamper plugin. now ..how to check image preloading or not

Comment: Well it might be a little tricky - again, if you're loading for the page the image is on, then the browser is going to have to load it anyway. The best you can do is hope to give the browser a "head start", so that it will start the HTTP transaction to fetch the image sooner. With TamperData you should see the GET for your image start up as one of the very first things after the initial GET for the page itself. If you see that, then you know it's working.